# validate iterator arguments SFINAE

Tags: c++, sfinae

I'm trying to validate iterator arguments, accept all iterator which are derived from,
base iterator class from `std` for given type.

the class snapshot looks like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

  class CardSet
{
    public:
        /** Add cards from range of cards pointed by iterators */
    template<typename Iter,
        typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<std::vector<int>::iterator, Iter>::value>>
    inline void AppendCards(const Iter& first, const Iter& last);


 private:
    std::vector<int> mCards;
};
```

and the template is defined outsite the class in a header:

```
template<typename Iter,
    typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<std::vector<int>::iterator, Iter>::value>>
void CardSet::AppendCards(const Iter& first, const Iter& last)

{
    mCards.insert(mCards.end(), first, last);
    // ...
}
```

problem is (in definition of function) this does not compile, it says "no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list.

I don't see any argument mismatch here, why does't work?

Comment: Fyi, I have serious doubts you want/need two different types. If the iterators are supposedly from the same sequence, you want them to be the same type. i.e. `class Iter` as your template argument, and `Iter first, Iter last` as your function arguments. That said, show the *caller* code, including setup, with a [mcve].

Comment: ah, yes, I updated my question for your first point.

Comment: ok, I also replace type to int, that should be enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @metablaster Reproducible here means that I can copy-paste your code and see the same error that you do.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://ideone.com/iBMg94). I prefer the first method in that link, but regardless, still need a [mcve].

Comment: OK, I have just copied my own code from the question, into new project in VS, and got no errors except what is asked in the question, if that is not enough to figure out the problem with compilation then I doubt any addition of code can help to make the question more clear.

Comment: The error MSVC 2019 shows me is that you specify default value for the typename in your definition. This is not allowed because default value(both for templates and functions ) need to be specified only in function declaration. not in the definiton.

Comment: @roycabouly yes, but removing default argument from definition does not help either. `"unable to match function definition to an existing declaration"`

Comment: @WhozCraig oh, appologies, I didn't see your first link, empty `typename` works, thanks!